# How are the reasons for closing determined?

Tags: support, close-reasons

If five users with at least 3k reputation vote to close a question, it gets closed with the closing reason chosen by the majority appearing as the official closing reason. There are five possible reasons for closing at MSE. So I'm curious what happens if there is no majority reason. What happens with the vote tallys 2:2:1, 2:1:1:1 and 1:1:1:1:1?

Comment: Well... we could use this question to find out. ;)

Comment: @ArthurFischer Please do! I'm serious. But leave a comment stating your closing reason afterwards for the record.

Comment: Closed as off topic...

Comment: Closed as non-constructive

Comment: (Also, if we want to make this scientific, please each person use a different closing reason, and moderators: please do not close at all. You have a binding vote which binds the reason)

Comment: Closed as not a real question

Comment: too localized, vote to close.

Comment: closed as duplicate ... looks like my reason wins.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks :-)

Comment: @GEdgar: This is because you are the only one which had a tenured position and all that, the rest of us are just Ph.D. students and postdocs... :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/151385 for the details on Meta.SO. It states

> What if multiple close reasons are used on a question?
>
> If a moderator participates in the closure, the reason the moderator
>   selects is displayed. Otherwise, the question gets closed with the
>   most frequently given reason. If there is a tie, the latest reason is
>   used. However, if multiple potential duplicates were suggested, all of
>   them will be displayed in the automatically generated "possible
>   duplicates" box.